# unable to receive callback from second view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, callback, delegates

I have got two view controllers. Im trying to pass data to the previous viewcontroller

I have the following code in my second view controller `CEPeoplePickerNavigationController`

```
@class CEPeoplePickerNavigationController;
@protocol CEPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)previousViewController:(CEPeoplePickerNavigationController *)controller itemToSend:(NSString *)item;
@end


@interface CEPeoplePickerNavigationController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>{
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) id < CEPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate> peoplePickerDelegate;
@end
```

When the user clicks the done button, following code will be exectied

```
- (void)doneAction:(id)sender
{
    [self.peoplePickerDelegate previousViewController:self itemToSend:@"From Previous VC"];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

In my first view controller, I have the following interface in header file and I have ofcourse implemented the previousViewController method in my first view controller where the data has to be received

```
@interface CallViewViewController : UIViewController<CEPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate>
@end
```

When I move from the first view controller to the second view controller, Im using the following code.

```
CEPeoplePickerNavigationController *nextVc = [[CEPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    nextVc.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:nextVc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But when the user clicks the done button from the second view controller, Im not receiving any callback in my first view controller. why so?

I have implemented the interface as following,

```
- (void)previousViewController:(CEPeoplePickerNavigationController *)controller itemToSend:(NSString *)item
{
    NSLog(@"from CEPeoplePickerNavigationController %@",item);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Following code works

```
if ([[CallViewViewController new] respondsToSelector:@selector(previousViewController:item:)]) {
    [self.viewCrtrlDelegate previousViewController:self item:@"Here I am"];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
else{
   NSLog(@"Your delegate was properly set");
}
```

But if I try it by following way, it is not working

```
if ([[self.viewCrtrlDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(previousViewController:item:)]) {
    [self.viewCrtrlDelegate previousViewController:self item:@"Here I am"];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
else{
   NSLog(@"Your delegate was properly set");
}
```

This is how Im instantiating the view controller.

```
CEPeoplePickerNavigationController *nextVc = [[CEPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];

    nextVc.viewCrtrlDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:nextVc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: the method is executed or not

Comment: Show the button action of Done button.

Comment: I have enclosed the button action for done

Comment: the call back method in first view controller is not being executed or called though I have implemented the `CEPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate` in my first view controller

Comment: any ideas?.....

Comment: can you attach your project

Comment: Can you show the implementation of CEPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate in your first VC.

Comment: I have enclosed the way I have implemented the delegate

Comment: Are you sure its the same `CEPeoplePickerNavigationController`? You are init the `CEPeoplePickerNavigationController ` without any rootViewController or anything related to storyboard, it shouldnt work when you present

Comment: Can you please explain ?

Comment: Please read the updated question

Comment: `CEPeoplePickerNavigationController` initialize should be using `storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier ` or `nibName`

Comment: I have tried it but still :(

Comment: The viewcontroller has got navigationviewcontroller in between. will it create any issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems absolutely correct but to get around all the possibilities.
Can you check whether your done button action has a check to know if the delegate methods is available or not in that class?

```
if ([self.viewCrtrlDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(previousViewController:item:)]) {
    [self.viewCrtrlDelegate previousViewController:self item:@"Here I am"];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
else{
   NSLog(@"Your delegate was properly set");
}
```

Comment: else loop is being executed

Comment: It means your delegate was not properly set.Check if you have provided the implementation of delegate method in your first class.

Comment: I have provided. I will update the issue that i have noticed

Comment: You can check if your instantiating the second class properly.
Like if you are instantiating the controller using  storyboard.
Then use this .
     ViewController2 *ctrl = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"identifier_of_your_controller_in_storyboard"];

Comment: Or if you have a sperate nib file you can use 
    ViewController2 *ctrl = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"your_nib_name" bundle:nil];

Comment: If i instantiate with storyboard, it throws the following error `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setPeoplePickerDelegate:]:`

Comment: Please check that you ViewController2 File in linked to the storyboard and you have provided the identifier over there to use it in your initialisation.

Comment: I have used the id `PeoplePicker` in both my storyboard and also int my code

Comment: What about the Class linking?Check for it ,if you have provided the class name in the inspector pane while opening the storyboard.

Comment: I have provided CEPeoplePickerNavigationController as class

Comment: If you second view controller is embed in navigation controller as mentioned by you in the comment thread of question.
You can use like
 UINavigationController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigation_identifier_in_sotoryboard"];

    ViewController2 *ctrl = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"contr_identfier"];
    
    ctrl.viewCrtrlDelegate = self;
    
    controller = [controller initWithRootViewController:ctrl];
    
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: stroll no effects bro :(